# Why is calculated Free & Total drive space capping out at 2G?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, hard-drive

I wrote a directory information utility and (because I, and the people I wrote this for collect & use vintage hardware,) made it compatible with DOS and Windows 9x as well as Windows XP/Vista/7/8 64-bit (because we also use those.)  The problem I'm running into is that in Windows 9x it's reporting available drive space and total drive space as 2G (well 1.9997 G) even on larger drives.  On Windows XP and beyond (32-bit or 64-bit,) it reports the drive sizes correctly.  In DOS, of course, this isn't an issue as the maximum size in DOS is 2G already.

The code I'm using is (DInfo.Path is the directory being accessed, with [0] being the drive letter - A, B, C, etc...):

```
_dos_getdiskfree(DInfo.Path[0] - 'A' + 1, &Free);

BlockSize = Free.sectors_per_cluster * Free.bytes_per_sector;

for (i = 0; i < BlockSize; i++) {
    DriveBytes += Free.total_clusters;
    if (DriveBytes < Free.total_clusters) ++DBOverflow;
    FreeBytes += Free.avail_clusters;
    if (FreeBytes < Free.avail_clusters) ++FBOverflow;
}
```

The only difference between the code in the DOS stub and the Windows portion of the executable is the _dos_getdiskfree is replaced with _getdiskfree instead.  I use unsigned __int32 variables in the above code (or unsigned long for the DOS code.)  I used 32 bit for compatibility and to reduce re-writing the code as much as possible when converting the DOS code to Windows code.  In Windows XP+ I could probably have simplified things by using __int64 variables, but again, I wasn't sure if Windows 9x would provide those or not.  I wasn't even sure if the 32-bit versions of Windows XP+ would allow it or not, and really didn't want to research it just streamline it a bit.  Even on older HW it works fast enough with the loop.

With the Overflow & Byte variables both 32 bit integers, the size should max out at 8 exabytes (kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes, petabytes, exabytes in case you were wondering,) and since the largest drives currently available are measured in single digit terabytes, that limit shouldn't cause a problem for a while.  At least it's doubtful to do so during my lifetime.

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like a backwards-compatibility thing; Windows 95 may be lying to you because it fears you won't be able to handle the truth.  Is the code running in 32-bit or 16-bit mode?  Are you certain that it isn't running the DOS version instead?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231497

Answer (score 0):

The [answer provided by Raymond Chen in a comment](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231497) has fixed the problem.  Using GetDiskFreeSpaceEx rather than GetDiskFreeSpace produced the correct results.

Comment: Please post your question about DOS 7.0 separately.  (Though I think the answer is that it can't be done.)

Comment: Perhaps you could précis the answer here, for the avoidance of link-rot.

Comment: Actually, it should be possible, as there are exe and com files already that do so (chkdsk.exe springs immediately to mind.)  They work just fine in DOS 7.x without Windows being loaded.  The problem is, from digging through a disassembly of chkdsk, it does it with DOS INT calls, and so far, those are the only methods I can find.  Still trying to get it to work right (keep getting 0 clusters, 0 sectors per cluster, 514 bytes per sector.)  I would really only want to do this with DOS 7.x but getting a DOS version at run time usually isn't that big a deal.

Comment: @Useless: that's pretty much it; the only essential information is that you need to use GetDiskFreeSpaceEx instead of GetDiskFreeSpace.

Comment: @user3399848: chkdsk works by actually analyzing the content of the volume directly.  I assumed you wouldn't want to do that, because it means locking the volume - but come to think of it that may not be a problem in your case.  You'd still need to partially re-implement FAT, but you might be able to borrow code from FreeDOS or something.

Comment: Pretty much.  The only time the direct access calls would be necessary are on a FAT32+ drive that doesn't have access to the WINAPI calls necessary.  The only instance I know of this taking place are Win9x (maybe some versions of NT, never worked with those,) that have been booted to command prompt only.  Also don't know much about ME, but everything Windows 2K and beyond don't give the option of DOS mode any more. (and my program seems to work fine in all of those, as it is.)